# Trouble unit testing service with the Router injected in the constructor in Angular 2

Tags: unit-testing, testing, karma-runner, angular

I'm trying to test a service that has the application router injected in its constructor. Following Julie Ralph's suggestions presented in AngularConnect conf 2015 (and her repository: https://github.com/juliemr/ng2-test-seed), 
I'm using Karma and Jasmine.

It follows the example service to be tested:

```
import { Router } from 'angular2/router';

export class ExampleService {
  constructor(router : Router) {
    this._router = router;
  }

  //...
}
```

Right now, I'm just asserting the truth. It follows the service test:

```
import { it, describe, expect, inject, beforeEachProviders, MockApplicationRef } from 'angular2/testing';
import { ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2/router';
import { provide, ApplicationRef } from 'angular2/core';

import { ExampleService } from 'example-service.js';

describe('ExampleService', () => {
  beforeEachProviders(() => [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS, ExampleService,
    provide(ApplicationRef, { useClass: MockApplicationRef })
  ]);

  it('should validate the truth', inject([ExampleService], (exService) => {
    expect(true).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

when I run the tests ( > karma start karma.config.js ), I get a TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Looking at the router.js source code, it looks like I should bootstrap at least one component before injecting router. Is there 
an easy way to inject the Router dependency in a test?

The Stacktrace:

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
>        ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
>        TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
>            at routerPrimaryComponentFactory (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.js:2963:27)
>            at Injector._instantiate (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js:11920:19)
>            at Injector._instantiateProvider (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js:11859:21)
>            at Injector._new (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js:11849:19)
>            at InjectorDynamicStrategy.getObjByKeyId (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js:11733:42)
>            at Injector._getByKeyDefault (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js:12048:33)
>            at Injector._getByKey (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js:12002:21)
>            at Injector._getByDependency (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js:11990:21)
>            at Injector._instantiate (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js:11887:32)
>            at Injector._instantiateProvider (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js:11859:21)
>            at Injector._new (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js:11849:19)
>            at InjectorDynamicStrategy.getObjByKeyId (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js:11733:42)
>            at Injector._getByKeyDefault (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js:12048:33)
>            at Injector._getByKey (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js:12002:21)
>            at Injector._getByDependency (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js:11990:21)
>            at Injector._instantiate (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js:11887:32)
>            at Injector._instantiateProvider (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js:11859:21)
>            at Injector._new (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js:11849:19)
>            at InjectorDynamicStrategy.getObjByKeyId (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js:11733:42)
>            at Injector._getByKeyDefault (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js:12048:33)
>            at Injector._getByKey (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js:12002:21)
>            at Injector._getByDependency (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js:11990:21)
>            at Injector._instantiate (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js:11887:32)
>            at Injector._instantiateProvider (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js:11859:21)
>            at Injector._new (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js:11849:19)
>            at InjectorDynamicStrategy.getObjByKeyId (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js:11733:42)
>            at Injector._getByKeyDefault (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js:12048:33)
>            at Injector._getByKey (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js:12002:21)
>            at Injector.get (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js:11804:19)
>            at C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/angular2/bundles/testing.dev.js:2477:25
>            at Array.map (native)
>            at Array.map (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js:1113:14)
>            at FunctionWithParamTokens.execute (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/angular2/bundles/testing.dev.js:2476:33)
>            at C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/angular2/bundles/testing.dev.js:2601:25
>            at Zone.run (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js:138:17)
>            at Zone.run (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/angular2/bundles/testing.dev.js:2544:30)
>            at runInTestZone (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/angular2/bundles/testing.dev.js:2588:23)
>            at Object. (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/angular2/bundles/testing.dev.js:2600:33)
>            at attemptAsync (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1819:24)
>            at QueueRunner.run (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1774:9)
>            at QueueRunner.execute (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1762:10)
>            at Spec.Env.queueRunnerFactory (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:627:35)
>            at Spec.execute (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:353:10)
>            at Object.fn (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:2360:37)
>            at attemptAsync (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1819:24)
>            at QueueRunner.run (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1774:9)
>            at QueueRunner.execute (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1762:10)
>            at Env.queueRunnerFactory (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:627:35)
>            at Object.fn (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:2345:13)
>            at attemptAsync (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1819:24)
>            at QueueRunner.run (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1774:9)
>            at C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1801:16
>            at C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1745:9
>            at queueRunnerFactory.onComplete (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:2348:17)
>            at QueueRunner.clearStack (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:605:9)
>            at QueueRunner.run (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1784:12)
>            at C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1801:16
>            at C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1745:9
>            at complete (C:/Users/LSANTOS/Desktop/ng2-test-seed/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:365:9)

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6325

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem solved, just need to provide the ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT.

```
import {ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT} from 'angular2/router';

class MockPrimaryComponent {
}

beforeEachProviders(() => [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  provide(ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT, {useClass: MockPrimaryComponent}),
  ExampleService,
  provide(ApplicationRef, { useClass: MockApplicationRef })
]);
```

Comment: Did you also manage setting up the router for a test using router.navigate()?

Comment: there is no such router_primary_component

Answer (score 3):

I know this post is related to the old router, but I thought it might be useful to answer this. Using angular version rc.1 with the new router, I got unit tests with the router, including testing navigateByUrl, by using this test within angular as inspiration:  https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/router/test/integration_spec.ts

saved me a lot of hastle

Here's a working example

```
import {setBaseTestProviders,beforeEachProviders,inject,it,describe,expect,beforeEach} from '@angular/core/testing'

import { Component,provide} from '@angular/core';
import {Routes,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,Route} from "@angular/router";

import {ComponentResolver} from '@angular/core';
import {Router,RouterOutletMap,RouteSegment,RouterUrlSerializer,DefaultRouterUrlSerializer} from '@angular/router';
import {SpyLocation} from '@angular/common/testing';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';
import {ComponentFixture, TestComponentBuilder} from '@angular/compiler/testing';

import {TEST_BROWSER_DYNAMIC_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS,TEST_BROWSER_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';



@Component({
  selector: 'some-component',
  template: `Blah!`,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class SomeComponent {
}

@Component({
  selector: 'another-component',
  template: `Blah!`,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class AnotherComponent {
}

@Component({
  selector: 'root-cmp',
  template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
@Routes([
    new Route({path: '/some-path',component:SomeComponent}),
    new Route({path: '/another-path',component:AnotherComponent})
    ])
export class RootCmp {
}

export const PROVIDERS_TESTING = [
    provide(RouterUrlSerializer, {useClass: DefaultRouterUrlSerializer}),
    RouterOutletMap,
    provide(Location, {useClass: SpyLocation}),
    provide(RouteSegment, {useFactory: (r) => r.routeTree.root, deps: [Router]}),
    provide(Router,{
        useFactory: (resolver, urlParser, outletMap, location) => new Router(
            "RootComponent", RootCmp, resolver, urlParser, outletMap, location),
            deps: [ComponentResolver, RouterUrlSerializer, RouterOutletMap, Location]
        }
    ),    
]

setBaseTestProviders(TEST_BROWSER_DYNAMIC_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS,[TEST_BROWSER_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS,PROVIDERS_TESTING]);

it('some test',inject([Router, TestComponentBuilder, Location], (router:Router, tcb:TestComponentBuilder, location:Location) => {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        tcb.createAsync(RootCmp).then(fixture=>{                                
            router.navigateByUrl('/some-path').then(()=>{
                expect(location.path()).toEqual('/some-path');
                resolve()   
            })
        })
    })
}))

it('another test',inject([Router, TestComponentBuilder, Location], (router:Router, tcb:TestComponentBuilder, location:Location) => {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        tcb.createAsync(RootCmp).then(fixture=>{                                
            router.navigateByUrl('/another-path').then(()=>{
                expect(location.path()).toEqual('/another-path');
                resolve()   
            })
        })
    })
}))
```